# How to get all active Mutation Observers on page?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I checked [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but couldn't find a way how to get list of active mutation observers on a page using javascript. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

What if you extend the MutationObserver like this:

```
class TrackedMutationObserver extends MutationObserver {

    static instances = []

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }

    observe(...args) {
        super.observe(...args);
        this.constructor.instances.push(this)
    }

    disconnect() {
        super.disconnect();
        this.constructor.instances = this.constructor.instances.splice(this.constructor.instances.findIndex(instance => instance === this), 1)
    }

    static getActive() {
        return this.instances
    }
}
```

and instead of using `MutationObserver` you instantiate `TrackedMutationObserver`

[TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-lw8t1rtDrXzvxM69mqF-tyK4n683MarXNrf3rjegzcIVsO2kbte37GURCVb8PAbKUAKAztQL7AdTQgM9R0vV8b2nD170FX0fhdZcUVfcNIw-MQ5y1cZF2fEjQ3DVJiHgfMkDWMUOX1SUOT3B4DyPKo41PC0MPHUNsIDO8qMfIiXwYjdyO3IA)

Comment: Good answer, however, for the disconnect method I noticed it'd never disconnect the last observer in the array. To fix that, I used `.filter()` isntead of both `.splice()` and `findIndex()`, here's the code: `this.constructor.instances = this.constructor.instances.filter(instance => instance !== this);`